# How to find digits of a number scaled to their positions?

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to find digits of a number scaled to their position?

For example:

- `'53'` → `['50', '3']`
- `'123'` → `['100', '20', '3']`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function generateCC(x) {
  var first_c = x.charAt(0);
  for(var i=0;i<x.length-1;i++)
    first_c += '0';
  var second_c = x-first_c;
  return [first_c, second_c];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean digits, with placeholder zeros.

Comment: Uh, what?  A "fraction" is, in reality, an unsolved division problem.  Any number of results could be reversed into a fraction.  But which one to use?  Example:  .5 = 1/2, or 10/20, or 25/50, etc...

Comment: Is it making sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function digit(num, n)
{
   return Math.floor(num / (Math.pow(10, n)) % 10
}
```

digit(53, 0) returns 3
digit(53, 1) returns 5

You could instead convert to string and access individual digits using string[]

```
var res = [];
var num = 53;
var str = num.toString();
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    res.push( parseInt(str[i]) * Math.pow (10, str.length - i - 1) );
}
```

res will be [ 50, 3 ]

Comment: it says [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 10000000, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]

Comment: Fixed it. Djdjdndndnns

Comment: sorry but now it says [15, 4]

Comment: Fixed. I accidentally put + instead of *

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick implementation I came up with.

```
function getDigitsScaled(x) {
    var i = '';
    return x.toString().split('')
            .reverse()
            .map(function(d) { return (d += i, i += '0', d); });
}
```

But, this will return the array in reverse order (`['3', '50']` rather than `['50', '3']`). This version will return them in the correct order:

```
function getDigitsScaled(x) {
    var s = x.toString(), i = Array(s.length).join('0');
    return s.split('')
            .map(function(d) { return (d += i, i = i.substr(1), d); });
}
```

The previous versions are designed to work with strings, but here's a version that works with numbers:

```
function getDigitsScaled3(x) {
    var i = 1, j = 10, arr = [];
    do {
        arr.push(x % j - x % i);
        i *= 10;
        j *= 10;
    }
    while (i < x);
    return arr;
}
```